# jquery prev() return undef

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After receiving the data via JSON and add content on a table, was used the event delegation to capture the links of this content, but when you click the link that was created dynamically want to access the prev () the tr element containing the data-id. But this is me returning undef. Can someone help me? The prev() is being called by editarComercial()

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function editarComercial(trthis) {
        alert($(trthis).prev().prev().data('id'));
    }

    function listaComercial(){

        url = BASE_URL + 'comercial/ajaxrequest/listagem';

        $.getJSON(url,function(data){

            var trs = [];
            $.each(data,function (key){

                tr = "<tr data-id=\""+data[key].id+"\">";
                tr += "<td>"+data[key].nome+"</td>";
                tr += "<td><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"edit-comercial\">Editar</a>";
                tr += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"del-comercial\">Excluir</a></td>";
                tr += "</tr>";

               trs.push(tr);
            });
            $("<tbody/>",{
                html: trs.join("")
            }).appendTo("#listagemComercial");
        });

    }

    $(document).on('click','a.edit-comercial',function(){
        editarComercial(this);
    });

    listaComercial();
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="content">
    <table id="listagemComercial">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.edit-comercial` doesn't have a previous element, it's the first element in the TD.

You probably wanted `closest()` instead, to traverse up to the row

```
function editarComercial(trthis) {
    alert( $(trthis).closest('tr').data('id') );
}
```

Comment: Also, the trthis variable is probably misnamed. It points to an <a> element, not a <tr> element.

Comment: Great! Thanks man (@adeneo) ... But, I not still understand the why from this. Why not exists previous element? I see this element on inspect's element browser. Anyway thank you..

Comment: @spectacularbob then the method prev() not up tree DOM? Only your sibling?

Comment: yes, prev() will only go to sibling nodes in the DOM.